# how to call javascript function from different div in html page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

i have this code, two scripts in the same html page. the first is into a div that contains a google map, and once the user clicks on a marker on the map, the name of the person on the marker should appear on another div.

```
<div id = "first">
  <div id ="map">
    <script type="text/javascript>

    [.. google map api code]

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: pos3,
          map: map,
          icon: "../images/RFlogo.png",
          // name = "roger",
          // lastname = "federer",
    });

   marker.addListener('click', function () {
            // 
   });
   </script>
 </div>
</div>

<div id ="second">
 <script type="text/javascript">

 write.document("Name: " + name + "\nLast name: " + last name);
 //how can i do to print the name on the marker ?
 </script>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need to put the script directly inside the element that you want the code to appear... you should find your element using document.findElementById("second").innerHTML = 'the text you want';

Comment: Inside the `click` listener, where you have `//`, that is where you can pick up any information you want from `marker` and do anything with it. But you won't be using `write.document()` - there is no such thing. And you won't be using `document.write()`either. It does exist but won't work for this. But there are a few ways to do it, including @CalvinNunes' fine suggestion - except it's `getElementById`. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done using `customInfo` property of markers.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    customerInfo:{name:"Vignesh"}
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(){
    console.log(this.customInfo.name);
});
```